# Node : Cannot find module common

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I was running a node server w/o any issue and for some purpose had to remove the node_modules dir and re-install the dependencies. Upon doing so and running the server again I get this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module './common'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\Cinde-Node\node_modules\debug\src\node.js:236:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

I installed `common` separately using `npm install common` but that didnt solve the problem.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Can you try `npm install --save common` and see if it is working?

Comment: if 'common' is you js file then make sure you have export it to access it anywhere.

Comment: can you show us code that is doing import of lib?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a line like
`require('./common');`
it should be 
`require('common')`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem like:

> Error: Cannot find module './sdam/common'

So I just removed the `node_modules` folder, then just ran command `npm i`.

That will download every dependencies mentioned in `package.json` file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34337963)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I tried running my express project. The following command helped me to fix the issue.

```
rm package-lock.json && rm -r node_modules && npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps
```